# How to add leading spaces to format a decimal?

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, decimalformat

Left image is what I have now. Right image is what I'm aiming for.

[image]

I need three spaces for the integer before the decimal place. If it's a 0 I just need one 0 to be displayed with two spaces before it. This is how I'm doing it but it's not working because it produces the left image. I need it to force three spaces before the decimal.

```
    mAttemptOneScore.setText(String.format("%3.2f", mScoreAttemptOne));
    mAttemptTwoScore.setText(String.format("%3.2f", mScoreAttemptTwo));
    mAttemptThreeScore.setText(String.format("%3.2f", mScoreAttemptThree));
    mAttemptFourScore.setText(String.format("%3.2f", mScoreAttemptFour));
    mTotalScore.setText(String.format("%3.2f", mFinalScore));
```

Comment: Even if someone gives you code to pad the string, I think you could still have formatting issue, especially if your font is not monospaced. You see, a space and a zero may not take up the same width in a non monospaced font, and in fact there may not even be a way to align everything using spaces.  A nicer way to proceed here might be to use a separate text view for the RHS of the scores.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using a different text view. [I am not doing it?](https://i.imgur.com/U64A1BJ.png)

Comment: No, I'm saying that everything to the right of the equals signs is a separate text view.  Then you can guarantee the alignment you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right now I have each text view to the right of the equal sign wrapping the content. I think I will have to set a static width to assure this. Didn't want to do this because space varies a lot by device size.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a fixed number of attempts.
In that case, the proper way to build your UI is using GridLayout: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

If you still want to use text-based formatting, there are a number of solutions.

1. Tab-based formatting

   `mAttemptTwoScore.setText(String.format("On %d attempt \t\t%d * %.2f\t=%3.2f", ...));`
2. HTML formatting, construct your UI using html and use this method

   `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public static Spanned getSpanned(String text) {
       Spanned spanned;
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
           spanned = Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
       else
           spanned = Html.fromHtml(text);
       return spanned;
   }`

   to assign HTML to TextView.
3. 3rd-party libraries, like https://github.com/thedathoudarya/WAGU-data-in-table-view. You should guarantee using monospaced font.

Comment: Thanks for this. But what I did to fix it is place the text view inside a frame layout with a fixed width big enough to hold the longest decimal I expect. Works great.

Comment: @Nico, nope. You can't guess, which font is used on user's device. You cant guess the font size used. You don't control the screen size and resolution. Absolutely no guarantee how would looks your layout after.

Comment: not an answer to his question. Offering alternative approach is acceptable if the exact question is answered first. "Use grid-layout" doesn't answer "how do I add leading spaces to format a decimal"